# RedisTemplate mock is only working in the test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, redis, microservices

```
Class A{
  
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    private String readFromCache(String bucket, String key) {
            Object object = redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(bucketName, key);
            System.out.println("----" + redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("1", "1"));
            String returnValue = "";
            if (Objects.nonNull(object))
                returnValue = object.toString();
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

Class B

```
    Class B extends A{
       
    someMethod(){
       readFromCache(bucketName , key);
      }
    }
```

Now when I am writing the test for method in class B i.e. someMethod().

```
     @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
            @SpringBootTest
            @ActiveProfiles("test")
            ClassBTest(){

            @InjectMocks
Class B
            
            @Mock
            @Qualifier("redisTemplate")
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
            
            @Mock
            HashOperations<String, Object, Object> hashOpertaions;
              
    @Test
               someMethodTest(){
             Mockito.when(redisTemplate.opsForHash()).thenReturn(hashOpertaions);
                Mockito.doReturn("aa").when(hashOpertaions).get(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
    someMethod();
    //assertions
               
        }
            }
```

I have observed that the redis template mock is generating in test class but not in Class A and class B

Inside ClassBTest
[image]

Inside class B
[image]

Why is the mock not working in class B and A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is resolved now. This works for me

```
@MockBean
    @Qualifier("redisTemplate")
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    @MockBean
    HashOperations<String, Object, Object> hashOpertaions;

    @MockBean
    RedisKeyValueAdapter redisKeyValueAdapter;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not injecting the mocks into the service that you are testing. It can be done with `@InjectMocks` before the classes that you want to test. You can try:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
ClassBTest(){

    @Mock
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
    
    @Mock
    HashOperations<String, Object, Object> hashOpertaions;

    @InjectMocks
    B objectOfB;  // this would inject the created mocks into the class
      
    @Test
    someMethodTest(){
        Mockito.when(redisTemplate.opsForHash()).thenReturn(hashOpertaions);
        Mockito.doReturn("aa").when(hashOpertaions).get(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
        objectOfB.someMethod();
        //assertions
       
   }
}
```

Comment: I am doing that, missed it while writing the question